# What brand of bicycle is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike, cruiser

Looking for the brand of this bike - like the style and color. Only have the photo

[image: like this color and style - looking for the brand]

Comment: HAH Good work @chrisH ! I started googling for "adelphi hotel" +bicycle and learned that is not an uncommon name for a hotel.
I was going to suggest you make inquiries via Email with these Adelphi hotels directly:   Melbourne / Liverpool / Las Vegas
Radial front spokes and double-pivot brake calipers says its modern-retro, and not old. There's no dynamo light, so its not Continental-European.

Answer (score 10):

A google reverse image search tells me it's a Martone Sweetzer (US) or Real (European version).

http://www.martonecycling.eu/product-EU-5-25-Womens_Real

From certain features of the frame (the bend in the top tube etc.) I'd say that's the same bike, but that your picture is of a slightly customised version with a different saddle and grips.

Comment: Bingo! :) You won

Comment: For info the "best guess" that Google came up with in the "search by image" feature was nonsense (an ordinary white flat-bar bike), but by replacing the best guess text with "bicycle" it was spot on.  Then I just had to contend with the Martone website which was designed to sell me a bike available where I am.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a Martone. 
However, if I may suggest, do not buy this bike, it is built to the absolute minimum of quality standards. 
If you like the integrated bar/basket, you can get one from copenhagen parts. This could be paired to any step-through-framed bike, 99.9% of which will be of a higher quality than a Martone.

Comment: Do you know that these bikes are particularly low quality? US$1200 is not department-store level (what folks here like to call a 'BSO').

Comment: I assembled a few and can confirm that all components are no-name chinese stuff with a thick layer of liquid paint on them. While it's maybe not quite a BSO it's most definitely way overpriced. 

That being said, maybe they've completely changed since last year! But the photo looks exactly like what I worked on.

Comment: @Sly-bonk Good to know. Mail order of partially assembled bikes only in the EU was a red flag. Also, OMG the colors!

Answer (score -1):

I would search for "Pininfarina bicycles". I saw one time bicycle with similar basket. The basket was very uncommon for me, because basket and the handlebar is one piece. That bicycle had nothing else in common with your bike, BUT when you browse for "Pininfarina bike",
[image]
 you will get models with similar to some extent upper tube bents.